# What is the image size in scientific paper if indicated as "a single, 1.5 or 2-column fitting image"?

Tags: academic-writing, scientific-publishing, science

I would like to submit my manuscript in ecology, containing Figures. However, in Author guidelines, I found that I have to

*Indicate per figure if it is a single, 1.5 or 2-column fitting image.*

What are those measures? In another journals I found (http://www.pitt.edu/~mcs2/teaching/biocomp/tutorials/journal_req.html):

- single column width (21 picas, 8.9 cm, 3.5 inches),
- a 1.5-column width (30 picas, 12.7 cm, 5 inches)
- a full two-column width (43 picas, 18.2 cm, 7.2 inches)

Are those measures the same for every journal? **Does it also mean, that in my paper I can use only 3 types of figures' widths, nothing between e.g. width of 6 inches?**

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

This is a good visualisation which helps alot.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I finally found it. It seems to vary by journal.

Here are ones related to **publication of artwork (figures and plots)** for Elsevier:

https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/artwork-and-media-instructions/artwork-sizing

*
*

[image: image width for Elsevier]

Comment: In inches: `30 mm = 1.1811 inch, 90 mm = 3.54331 inch, 140 mm = 5.51181 inch, 190 mm = 7.48031 inch`